# Why this animation is not starting

Tags: html, css

I have found cool 3x3 grid loader [here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ut6qtnsw). But after I copy and paste the CSS and HTML properties into my document - the animation is not starting.

HTML

```
<div class="loading"> 
            <div class="cube cube1"></div> 
            <div class="cube cube2"></div> 
            <div class="cube cube3"></div> 
            <div class="cube cube4"></div> 
            <div class="cube cube5"></div> 
            <div class="cube cube6"></div> 
            <div class="cube cube7"></div> 
            <div class="cube cube8"></div> 
        </div>
```

CSS

```
body{ 
background:#333; 
} 

div.loading{ 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%; 
    margin-top: -75px; 
    margin-left: -75px; 
    width: 153px; 
    height: 153px; 
} 

div.cube{ 
    position: absolute; 
    margin: -1px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; 
    background: #222; 
    display: inline-block; 
} 

div.cube1 {
    margin: 000px 0px 0px 000px;
    animation: cube1 .5s linear 0 infinite;
}

div.cube2 {
    margin: 000px 0px 0px 051px;
    animation: cube2 .5s linear 0 infinite;
}

div.cube3 {
    margin: 000px 0px 0px 102px;
    animation: cube3 .5s linear 0 infinite;
} 

div.cube4 {
    margin: 051px 0px 0px 000px;
    animation: cube4 .5s linear 0 infinite;
} 

div.cube5 {
    margin: 051px 0px 0px 051px;
}

div.cube6 {
    margin: 051px 0px 0px 102px;
    animation: cube6 .5s linear 0 infinite;
} 

div.cube7 {
    margin: 102px 0px 0px 000px;
    animation: cube7 .5s linear 0 infinite;
} 

div.cube8 {
    margin: 102px 0px 0px 051px;
    animation: cube8 .5s linear 0 infinite;
} 

@-webkit-keyframes cube1 { 
    0%  {
        margin: 000px 0px 0px 000px;
    }
    25% {
        margin: 000px 0px 0px 000px;
    } 
    50% {
        margin: 000px 0px 0px 051px;
    } 
    75% {
        margin: 000px 0px 0px 051px;
    } 
    100% {
        margin: 000px 0px 0px 051px;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cube2 { 
    0% {
        margin: 000px 0px 0px 051px;
    } 
    25% {
        margin: 000px 0px 0px 051px;
    } 
    50% {
        margin: 000px 0px 0px 102px;
    }
    75% {
        margin: 000px 0px 0px 102px;
    } 
    100% {
        margin: 000px 0px 0px 102px;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cube3 { 
    0% {
        margin: 000px 0px 0px 102px;
    } 
    25% {
        margin: 051px 0px 0px 102px;
    }
    50% {
        margin: 051px 0px 0px 102px;
    }
    75% {
        margin: 051px 0px 0px 102px;
    } 
    100% {
        margin: 051px 0px 0px 102px;
    } 
}

@-webkit-keyframes cube4 {
    0% {
        margin: 051px 0px 0px 000px;
    }
    25% {
        margin: 051px 0px 0px 000px;
    } 
    50% {
        margin: 051px 0px 0px 000px;
    } 
    75% {
        margin: 000px 0px 0px 000px;
    }
    100% {
        margin: 000px 0px 0px 000px;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cube6 { 
    0% {
        margin: 051px 0px 0px 102px;
    } 
    25% {
        margin: 102px 0px 0px 102px;
    } 
    50% {
        margin: 102px 0px 0px 102px;
    } 
    75% {
        margin: 102px 0px 0px 102px;
    } 
    100% {
        margin: 102px 0px 0px 051px;
    } 
} 

@-webkit-keyframes cube7 { 
    0% {
        margin: 102px 0px 0px 000px;
    } 
    25% {
        margin: 102px 0px 0px 000px;
    } 
    50% {
        margin: 102px 0px 0px 000px;
    } 
    75% {
        margin: 051px 0px 0px 000px;
    } 
    100% {
        margin: 051px 0px 0px 000px;
    } 
} 

@-webkit-keyframes cube8 { 
    0% {
        margin: 102px 0px 0px 051px;
    } 
    25% {
        margin: 102px 0px 0px 051px;
    } 
    50% {
        margin: 102px 0px 0px 051px;
    } 
    75% {
        margin: 102px 0px 0px 051px;
    } 
    100% {
        margin: 102px 0px 0px 000px;
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: What browser isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pay attention at the vendor prefixes. You declare the keyframes with `-webkit-` but doesn't assign the same way on the css `animation`:

```
div.cube6 {
  margin: 051px 0px 0px 102px;
  animation: cube6 .5s linear 0 infinite; <-- Needs webkit too
}
```

That way can work for `-webkit-` browsers. Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YEKHb/)**.

Then you may need to make `keyframes` and `animation` declaration with all vendor prefixes and without it.

Comment: can u show my an example of how to do that on one cube ? - I mean how to assign this to animation...

Comment: It's already working for chrome in the fiddle I link you  just need to add the other declarations. @user3219821

Comment: @user3219821 check this http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Comment: The website You gave me helped me a lot. Thank You :) Now it is working perfectly ! Thank You !!!

Comment: @user3219821 you need to modify the structure of animation your declaration syntax is wrong check this work in Firefox http://jsfiddle.net/YEKHb/3/ .... If this was helpful don't forget to mark it as the final answer